# Why can't my div tags go side-by-side in Dreamweaver CC Fluid Grid Layout?

Tags: html, css

I'm using Dreamweaver CC and trying to do a Fluid Grid Layout.  I want my 3 div tags to be side-by-side.  I've read and followed a number of examples but I have no luck with it.  Can someone please help me figure out what's going on?

Thanks for any help!

Here's the HTML file:

```
 <!doctype html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="gridContainer clearfix">
     <div id="container" class="fluid ">
          <div id="left" class="fluid ">left </div>
          <div id="center" class="fluid ">center</div>
          <div id="right" class="fluid ">right</div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS file:

```
 @media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {

 .gridContainer {
  width: 88.5%;
   max-width: 1232px;
  padding-left: 0.75%;
  padding-right: 0.75%;
  margin: auto;
  clear: none;
  float: none;
  margin-left: auto;
 }

 #container {
 }
 #left {
  float:left;
    margin: 01.5%;
    width:30%;
  background-color:red;

 }
 #center {
   float:left;
   margin: 01.5%;
   width:30%;
   layout:inline;
   background-color:green;
 }
 #right {
   float:left;
   margin: 01.5%;
   width:30%;
   background-color:blue;
 }

 .zeroMargin_desktop {
  margin-left: 0;
 }
 .hide_desktop {
 display: none;
 }
 }
```

Comment: your example work as expected for screen with min-width: 769px, what is your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#sides{
margin:1.5%;
}
#left{
float:left;
width:30%;
overflow:hidden;
}
#center{
float:left;
width:30%;
overflow:hidden;
} 
#right{
float:left;
width:30%;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="gridContainer clearfix">
  <div id="container" class="fluid ">
  <div id="left" class="fluid ">left </div>
  <div id="center" class="fluid ">center</div>
  <div id="right" class="fluid ">right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The code works if I don't use the Dreamweaver Grid Layout.  I'm editing the css in  Dreamweaver cc under the desktop layout section of the css file.  Since the layout works if I just use the code in a regular text editor and create an html file for it, I'm suspecting that something about the gridContainer clearfix or some parent container is causing it not to work.  Any ideas?